# What is the explanation for length of a block?

Tags: ruby, block

I am wondering about this line:

```
 { |i| (num % i) == 0}.length == 0
```

Can someone explain what happens using `length` on a block? I am trying to answer a rubeque problem about prime factors:

```
divisors = Array.new
 for d in 2..(num)
  divisors << d if (num % d) == 0
end

primes = divisors.select do |num| 
 (2..(num-1)).select { |i| (num % i) == 0}.length == 0
end
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading about  `select`, and `reject` and how they are used with arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's calling `length` on the result of `(2..(num-1)).select { |i| (num % i) == 0}` — which is an array — not on the block.